# NSMutableDictionary - entries appear to be over-written by each addition

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I'm fairly new to Objective-C; but have been coding for years and this one really stumps me.

I'm trying to build an iPhone app and wanted to create a "settings" screen which will use a Table format. (Xcode 5.1.1).

I want to future proof the main Settings screen and make it easy for the application coding by hiding the "hard work" in subroutines/methods.

I may be getting too clever but I've created a class for each 'setting' that contains screen prompts, default values etc and using an Enum to cross-reference it (so the compiler will highlight typos etc)

The problem I'm encountering is that when I add entries to my NSMutableDictionary and use lldb to print the values; every entry seems to have the same "key" and values. I've tried converting the eNum to an NSNumber and also as an NSString -- no difference in the result - so I'm obviously doing something else daft but just can't see it

The following code is from various .m & .h files, I've omitted boring stuff that you always "have to have" to keep it short

```
// basic x-ref I want to use in my code
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, ConfigurationType)  {
    unDefined = -1,
    Server = 0,
    Id  = 1,
    Phone  = 2
};
// definition for a "single" Settings value
@interface SettingDefinition : NSObject
@end

@implementation SettingDefinition

ConfigurationType _cfgType;
NSString *_cfgName;
NSString *_screenTitle;
NSString *_value;

- (NSString *)description
{
    NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@: x%p Type=%d dbKey=%@ '%@' -> %@>", className, self, _cfgType, _cfgName, _screenTitle, _value];
}
- (id)initType:(ConfigurationType)cfgOption
      withDbKey: (NSString*)dbKey
      asOptionTitle:(NSString*)cfgTitle
      withValue:(NSString*)itmValue
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _screenTitle = cfgTitle;
        _cfgName = dbKey;
        _cfgType = cfgOption;
        _value = itmValue;
    }
    return self;
}
@end


@interface Configuration : NSObject
@end
@implementation Configuration {
   NSMutableDictionary *Settings;  // List of Setting structures
};

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        Settings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

        [self add:Server withDbKey:@"Server" asOptionTitle:@"Server"];
        [self add:Id     withDbKey:@"Id"     asOptionTitle:@"Your ID"];
        [self add:Phone  withDbKey:@"Phone"  asOptionTitle:@"Phone No."];
    }  
    return self;
}
- (void)    add:(ConfigurationType)cfgOption
      withDbKey:(NSString*)dbKey
  asOptionTitle:(NSString*)cfgTitle
{
     NSString * itmValue = [self configurationValue: cfgOption cfgName:dbKey];
     SettingDefinition *x = [[SettingDefinition alloc]
                               initType:  cfgOption
                               withDbKey:   dbKey
                               asOptionTitle:  cfgTitle
                               withValue: itmValue];
     [Settings setObject:x forKey:[self asKey:cfgOption]]; 
}

- (NSString *) asKey:(ConfigurationType) settingType {
    NSString *rc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", settingType];
    return rc;
}
- (NSString *) configurationValue:(ConfigurationType) settingType {
    // returns a suitable value from my system setup
    // which is initially a null value until the user sets everything up
}
```

the debug window shows the following when I break after the final call to [self add: ...]

```
    (lldb) po Settings
    {
       0 = "<SettingDefinition: x0x8e7c280 Type=2 dbKey=Phone 'Phone No.' -> (null)>";
       1 = "<SettingDefinition: x0x8c703a0 Type=2 dbKey=Phone 'Phone No.' -> (null)>";
       2 = "<SettingDefinition: x0x8e7c310 Type=2 dbKey=Phone 'Phone No.' -> (null)>";
    }
```

The (null) is obviously due to no data in 'value' yet; but why do they all show as 'Phone'; if I break after the second call to [self add:..] they all show as 'Id'

---

UPDATE:

DOH! obviously they're globals (I've been using another IDE where everything is local until exposed) .. If I enclose them in braces in the implementation as the documentation states then the exhibited problem vanishes. I have properties to access the variables but as the setter does more than just set the memory, I thought I'd need my "own" variables to hold the data.. said it was something daft .. thank you!

Comment: `_value` the other three variables are globals, not instance variables. Read up on the syntax for declaring instance variables. Additionally, this has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: oops, looks like I missed the "and" after "_value" in the first sentence...

Comment: Make your values in SettingDefinition be properties.  (Or, better, just replace SettingDefinition with an NSDictionary.)

Comment: After each [self add...] put this line: "NSLog(@"Settings %@",Settings);  lldb might be lying to you.